# Webpack 5 loading external images from styles

Tags: css, image, url, webpack, sass

Webpack was added to a large project and slowly migrating things over. There are 2 main folders in project root, `build` and `code`. `build` is root for webpack and `code` is root for webroot. I currently have all my app images in `code/includes/img/` and css and scss in `code/includes/css`. However the scss files are called from `build/src/style.scss`

```
import "../../code/includes/css/sheetone.scss";
```

The public build folder is set to be at `code/includes/app/` so the final output css file will be at `code/includes/app/css/style.css`

In sheetone.scss images are loaded with `url()` like this `url(../img/myimage.jpg);` but webpack isn't failing to detecting on build. I tried to use `resolve-url-loader` and tweaked a handful of things but no luck.

If I set images to `url(../../code/includes/img/myimage.jpg)`, everything builds but the output path in the css file and manifest remain as `../../code/includes/img/myimage.jpg`

I'm I doing something wrong with webpack setup or do I need to do some hack step to rewrite the image paths since things are loaded in an untraditional way?

```
...
            {
                test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                exclude: /\.module.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
                use: [
                     MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: false,
                            importLoaders: 3,
                            modules: false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "resolve-url-loader",
                        options: {}
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: false,
                            postcssOptions: {
                                ident: "postcss",
                                plugins: [
                                    postcssPresetEnv({
                                        browsers: "last 5 versions",
                                        autoprefixer: {
                                            grid: true
                                        }
                                    })
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                sourceMapContents: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
...
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "styles/[name].[contenthash].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ],
...
```

Comment: I updated `resolve-url-loader` and i'm now able to find files based off just `../img/myimage.jpg` but the returned output is `../../code/includes/img/myimage.jpg` is there a way to modify that?